# Rotate an AVAsset with AVAssetExportSession

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-graphics, core-video

I'm trying to rotate a video to its correct orientation using an `AVAssetExportSession` and I always get the following error:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11841 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (AVFoundationErrorDomain error -11841.)"
```

That translates to `AVErrorInvalidVideoComposition` but I cannot see anything wrong with my video composition. Here's the code:

```
AVAssetTrack *sourceVideo = [[avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] lastObject];
AVAssetTrack *sourceAudio = [[avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] lastObject];
CGAffineTransform preferredTransform = [sourceVideo preferredTransform];

AVMutableComposition *composition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                            preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality] autorelease];

[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration)
                               ofTrack:sourceVideo
                                atTime:kCMTimeZero
                                 error:nil];

if( !CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(preferredTransform) ) {

    AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    videoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake([avAsset naturalSize].height, [avAsset naturalSize].width);
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, compositionVideoTrack.naturalTimeScale);

    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:sourceVideo];
    [instruction setTransform:preferredTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *videoTrackInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    videoTrackInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration);
    videoTrackInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:instruction];

    [videoComposition setInstructions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:videoTrackInstruction]];

    exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition;
}

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                                                            preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

[compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration)
                               ofTrack:sourceAudio
                                atTime:kCMTimeZero
                                 error:nil];

exporter.outputURL = tempPathUrl;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{ }];
```

What could be wrong with the composition? I've been through the documentation and cannot see anything wrong with it so far.

Comment: Did you ever find out why you were getting that error?

Comment: ok, so it seems half of the bounty goes to GingerBreadMane, for an answer that doesn't work. It seems that there isn't really a community of iOS developers on StackOverflow. It's a shame.

Comment: Suffering from a similar problem on iOS 7.0.3... my code which is similar works when I use a just recorded video, but fails when I choose a video from the library. It makes very little sense to me. Will let you know when I find a solution. May have to not use AVExportSession.

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with your frame duration.  You're using 
`CMTimeMake(1, naturalTimeScale)`
You should check the naturalTimeScale as it does not always equal the fps.  See the [AVFoundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/05_MediaRepresentations.html) 'Representations of Time' for more info.

Comment: do you know how to get the FPS for a video asset?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the order of width and height arguments is incorrect.
You have:

```
    videoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake([avAsset naturalSize].height, [avAsset naturalSize].width);
```

Shouldn't it be

```
    videoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake([avAsset naturalSize].width, [avAsset naturalSize].height);
```

instead?

Answer (score 0):

The error is from how you set `instruction`.

```
... videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:sourceVideo]
```

`sourceVideo` is not a member of the composition. In your case this should be `compositionVideoTrack`.